# Add hashtags to twitter api status update

Tags: php, api, twitter

Been trying to figure out the array for a while now but I can't get a hashtag posted with the tweet, the tweet itself is posting just fine, just not with the hashtag, my code is below:

```
$tweetmsg='testing'; //this is just an example of the variable
$connection->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $tweetmsg, 'entitites' => array('hashtags' => array('text' => 'test'))));
```

Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

API library i'm using: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use:

`$tweetmsg='testing #one #two #three';`

And it should work, unless you are changing `#` into an html entity or stripping it.

Edit:
As a tip, I'll tell you that it might be easier to use https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php instead of your library.

Comment: *Doh* I've been thinking about it too hard, that didn't come to mind. I can up your answer but it is not the actual answer.

I still want to know how to do this through the api.

Comment: It should be working with the api, it doesn't show up on your tweet? What shows on your tweet?

Comment: It shows up in the tweet yes, but what I mean is that there's a part in the array for that, I might have to strip hashtags in the future so I can't accept this as a definite answer. It's a quick fix, but I need to know how to do this using the api parameter

Comment: Hastags are always posted inside (or appended to) the message. There's no specification for separate hashtags at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update or https://twitteroauth.com/

Comment: What you can do is maybe a regex, if you need to filter them out for other users posting.

Comment: The example return from the status update call has a hashtag parameter doesnt it? I even tried in my browser and I saw the hashtag array

Comment: Yes, there is a hashtag field in the response, however, just because an api includes certain fields in the response, it doesn't mean you can query using those fields. For it to be accepted, it has to be specified in the `request documentation`, which is not.

Comment: If you submit `$tweetmsg='testing #one #two #three';` that field will be populated in the response. If you don't include hashtags on your message, it will return empty. That response it's just telling you, which tags Twitter recognized in your status update message, because if you include too many, only a few will be accepted.

Comment: Ok thank you I saw the specified params but just wanted to do things the right way so thought I could have specified it in the request. Will mark as answered, thanks.